# OpenCL force the number of registers

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

With CUDA, it is possible to force the compiler not to use more than N registers per thread using the compilation option:

```
--maxrregcount=N
```

**Is it possible with OpenCL? How?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this completely answers your question, but it is the closest I think is available.

'Max register usage per thread can be set by giving the clBuildProgram() the "-cl-nv-maxrregcount=n" option.'

From:
http://openvidia.sourceforge.net/index.php/OpenCL

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to partially answer my question though. The "nv" must mean "nvidia", therefore this option is platform-dependant.
It may be the only way to do it, but then, what is the option for other constructors?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned that I wasn't sure if it was what you were looking for. I'm not sure there is a generic way to specify the number of registers for any platform. Nvidia implements a lot of functionality on top of the base OpenCL specification.

Comment: Not sure if a generic way to set a maximum register number would make a lot of sense, because the _reason_ for doing so and the _number of registers_ you would want to set are platform specific anyway.